# git rebase --onto never gets past rewinding head

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have the following branches:

```
 ─┬──────────────────────────────────────┬──  master
  │                                      │
  │                                      │
  │                                      └── staging
  │
  │
  └─X───Y─┬─────────────────────────────────  develop
          │                         ▲
          │                         │
          └────A────────B──────C────┴──┬────  feature/abc
                                       │
                                       │
                                       └────  merge/feature/abc
```

Quick explanation of each one:

- master: this is the production branch - anything merged here goes to production.
- staging: this branch is used to temporarily group a bunch of different features that will go to production together as a release. Before a release, a fresh staging is cut from master.
- develop: mainline branch - regular branch that features are continually integrated into, as they are completed.
- feature/abc: a typical feature branch, cut from develop.
- merge/feature/abc: a working branch that I am trying to rebase, so that I can prepare the feature to be rebased off staging, as I prepare to do a release. (I just don't want to mess up the **feature/abc**.)

I want to make the **merge/feature/abc** rebased off staging, so that it contains only the relevant commits in **feature/abc**. i.e. I want **merge/feature/abc** to contain only commits A, B, and C, but not X and Y. This would happen after the **feature/abc** branch has been merged and tested on **develop**.

According to the [git manual](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing), the commands I want is:

```
git rebase --onto staging develop merge/feature/abc
```

When I do that, the output says:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
```

... and that's it - no other output. It just stops. As I understand it, there's supposed to be more output as `git rebase` applies commits. The **merge/feature/abc** branch does get rebased, but it does **not* contain any commits from feature/abc, if I do `git log`. If I run `git status`, it says:

```
On branch merge/feature/abc
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

If I run `git diff staging`, there is no diff. So it's basically reset to staging.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your graph is correct, then what you're seeing is indeed odd. (At least I'm not noticing anything wrong with your commands.) Can you try checking out staging (or creating an equivalent branch) and merging in either `feature/abc` or `merge/feature/abc`. The result may provide some additional insight. For example, if comparing staging before and after the merge has no changes, then all of those commits (or their equivalents) are already in `staging`.

Comment: @TTT I tried creating a branch off `staging` (called `staging-testmerge`) and ran `git merge merge/feature/abc`. It brings in a whole bunch of work, but not any of the commits specific to `feature/abc`. (I know because I tagged them all with the ticket #.) There are a bunch of conflicts too, from various work. The newest commit is the same as latest on `master` from last week. The commits in `feature/abc` from yesterday don't get merged in.

Comment: By the way, I can confirm that the commits in `feature/abc` are definitely not on `staging` already. I did `git checkout staging` and `git log` to confirm they're not.

Comment: Maybe you didn't complete the merge? When you merge in your branch, if there are conflicts, then you have to resolve the conflicts first and then complete the merge before the new commits show up in the branch.

Comment: Ah you're right @TTT, when I do `git checkout staging-testmerge  && git merge merge/feature/abc`, the reason I didn't see the commits originally is that there were conflicts in one of the files from `feature/abc`. If I resolve conflicts and complete the merge, then the commits from `feature/abc` appear in `git log` on `staging-testmerge`.

Comment: UPDATE: I think I have it working. Here's what I did: 1) Upgraded `git` to latest version. (2.22.0 -> 2.32.0). This did have an effect on the output of `git reflog show --no-abbrev feature/abc`. It's now much shorter, and I can easily tell the commit when I created the `feature/abc` branch.  2) Ran `git rebase --onto staging 9d101`, where 9d101 is the commit when I created the `feature/abc` branch. That seems to give me the rebase result I'm looking for. (Note I'm not using `develop` as the upstream.)

Answer (score 1):

This command:

> ```
> git rebase --onto staging develop merge/feature/abc
> ```

is short for:

```
git checkout merge/feature/abc
git rebase --onto staging develop
```

Here `develop` is the *`upstream`* argument, which should disable fork-point mode.  If for some reason it *does not* disable fork-point mode, adding `--no-fork-point` might help, but in any case, you might wish to run:

```
git log develop..merge/feature/abc
```

to see which commits would be candidates for copying here.  If the list is empty, that's the answer right away: there are no candidate commits to be copied.  If the list *isn't* empty, the next step is to examine these candidate commits:

- Any merge commits will be omitted.  Are the listed commits all merges?  If so, they will all be omitted.
- Any commits whose *patch ID* matches one in the upstream will be omitted.

This second point is what [TTT is alluding to in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68386512/git-rebase-onto-never-gets-past-rewinding-head#comment120864578_68386512):

> ... (or their equivalents) ...

Finding patch-ID-equivalent commands is a bit trickier.  The `--left-right --cherry-mark` options to `git log` / `git rev-list`, and the `git cherry` command, can do this.  When using `--cherry-mark` with `git log` or `git rev-list`, it's necessary to use the three-dot symmetric difference operator:

```
git log --left-right --cherry-mark --oneline develop...merge/feature/abc
```

The cherry-mark option makes `git log` (or `git rev-list`) run each commit through the patch-ID generator and then marks equivalent commits with `=` instead of `<` or `>`.  If there are commits listed by `git log develop..merge/feature/abc`, they would be right-hand-side `>` commits in this output; if they become marked with `=`, they're already *in* `develop` (or more precisely, Git thinks they are) so `git rebase` does not copy them.

If this is the issue, the `--reapply-cherry-picks` flag can help.  This flag is relatively new, having first appeared in Git 2.27.0.

Note: a command for listing everything all at once, with merge commits omitted without you having to do anything, is:

```
git rev-list --left-right --cherry-mark --no-merges develop...merge/feature/abc
```

Only commits marked `>` would be copied.  (Consider using `git log --oneline` for this as well, since that shows subject lines.)

Comment: Thanks for all this good info. The output of `git log develop..merge/feature/abc` is indeed nothing, which I don't understand, because there are definitely commits I made in `feature/abc` yesterday (`merge/feature/abc` is merged from `feature/abc`). I should add that `feature/abc` has already been merged into `develop` (via a merge request), since develop is the integration branch where work is merged as it's completed.

Comment: By the way, `git log --left-right --cherry-mark --oneline staging..merge/feature/abc` has a bunch of output  - is that what you meant @torek? Although its output includes both the commits I want (A, B, and C) and ones I don't (X, Y). Commits like A, B, and C are all straightforward commits, not merges or anything.

Comment: Addressing second comment first: No, `--left-right` must be used with the *three*-dot symmetric difference syntax—with the two-dot syntax, it's meaningless and ignored. With symmetric difference, you'll see commits reachable from the left starting point but not the right (now marked with `<`) and commits reachable from the right starting point but not the left (now marked with `>`). Adding `--cherry-mark` changes the markings.

Comment: Addressing first comment: If `develop..merge/feature/abc` is empty, there are no commits to copy, which completely explains the rebase behavior. The merge is probably the reason: `develop` now contains all the commits already. Remember that the set of commits contained in some branch changes dynamically, and merges suddenly include a whole bunch of commits that weren't there before.

Comment: If you have merge commits, the drawing needs to have more arrows in it. (Connections from commits to parents are one-way *arcs*, in graph theory terms; merges are commits—vertices or nodes in the graph—that have two or more outgoing parent arcs.)

Comment: Ah I didn't realize that it mattered that `feature/abc` had already been merged back into `develop`. Sorry I wasn't clear about that. I've updated the diagram and wording of my original post to make that clear. However, I also came up with a solution which *seems* to work (see last comment in thread on original post), but the only thing that's different there is that I used a commit for the the upstream in the rebase.

Comment: Using the specific commit as the rebase *`upstream`* argument is probably the method you wanted all along. I never liked the word "upstream" here; I prefer something like "limiter" or "dontcopy" or similar.